# What is String Local Memory in Java?

Tags: java, string, memory, jvm

In a JVM the memory is split into Method Area ,Stack ,Heap , Temp and Registry . what is String Local Memory  ? Does this exists ? If so when does it gets allocated or assigned ?
Appropriate Usage of this  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by the term "String Local Memory", but there is such a thing as String literal pooling in the VM whereby String literals are pooled (and reused).  See section  3.10.5 in the Java language spec:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html#100960

The other things you mention above are covered in detail in the Runtime Data Areas section of the VM spec:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html#1732

Hope that explains a bit more (with correct terminology).

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard of it before, and a Google search doesn't find any mention of it. Could you tell us where you've heard of "string local memory" for Java? I don't believe it's a standard term.

(I'm not really sure what you mean by "temp" or "registry" either as far as the JVM is concerned.)

Comment: This was Question asked in an Interview by a Java Architect . Still in search of this strange terminology :)

Comment: Jon is there any other memory in JVM excluding this Method Area ,Stack ,Heap , Temp and Registry  ?

Comment: @Srinivas: As I said, I'm not even sure about "temp" and "registry". By "method area" I assume you mean the JITted code. It sounds like this Java architect was getting confused, possibly with the string literal pool as mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: Thanks , i would to know which part of memory does Return types in Java is Stored ?

Comment: @Srinivas: Return *types*? It's not really clear what you mean. If you mean return *values*, they usually end up on the stack, when the method returns.

Answer (score 3):

> In a JVM the memory is split into
>   Method Area ,Stack ,Heap , Temp and
>   Registry.

No it isn't. It is split into stacks, the heap, the method area, and the constant pool. See [the JVM Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html#1732)

> what is String Local Memory?

No idea. What are 'Temp' and 'Registry'?

Wherever you got this from it is erroneous.

Answer (score 2):

Never heard of "string local memory".  I've heard of "thread local" memory, though.  That's where each thread that accesses a given ThreadLocal object gets a different value, depending entirely on which thread it is.  I've yet to need to use it -- feels too magical, if you ask me.

See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html for a bit more detail.

I mention this because "string" and "thread" mean quite similar things in the context of "long, flexible, very very skinny bits of material", and back-and-forth translation could account for the confusion.